# How does a child(ren) indicate that their finished loading for React.Suspense?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm going through the [Suspense](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/Suspense) guide, but I am having trouble understanding what is the indicator to say it's completed.

There's a note that indicates this

> Only Suspense-enabled data sources will activate the Suspense component. They include:
>
> - Data fetching with Suspense-enabled frameworks like Relay and Next.js
> - Lazy-loading component code with lazy

It also notes:

> Suspense does not detect when data is fetched inside an Effect or event handler.

The first example sounds like there is a way of signaling that something is completed, but I can't find the information.

So is there any way of doing this or is Suspense not feasible in a react native context?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question from somewhere else?